# How to assign outcomes of rand() function to be (H ,T ) not (0 ,1)

Tags: matlab

I want to generate sequence of toss outcomes of n trials using the help of rand() function. I read about rand() from MATLAB reference code that rand() generates 0 and 1 or random numbers within specified range, how I can make the outcome of rand() to be variable H and T - that represent head and tail- ?

Sample Code, let 1 be H and 0 is T:

```
n = 10;
x = rand(1,n)<0.5;
t = 1:10;
plot(t,x);
title('outcomes of tossing a coin 10 times');
xlabel('trials');
ylabel('outcome');
axis([1 10 0 1.2]);
display(x);
```

Command Window

```
x =

  1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty easy.  Create a cell array of strings that contains two strings: `Heads` and `Tails`:

```
outcome = {'Heads', 'Tails'};
```

Next, you can use `rand` like you did before, but then cast this to `double` and add 1 so that you get values that are 1 and 2.  The reason why you need this is because you can use this output to index into `outcome`, as MATLAB begins accessing values at index 1.  However, if you create your `logical` vector of `rand(1,n) < 0.5` then add 1 to this result, the output will be coalesced into a `double` anyway so you would implicitly be casting the result.

You can then use this to index into `outcome` to get your desired results.  To reproduce this on my end:

```
%// Set seed for reproducibility
rng(123123);
x = rand(10,1) < 0.5; %// Generate random vector of logical 0s and 1s

%// Cast to double then add with 1 so we can generate a vector of 1s and 2s
x = x + 1;

%// Declare that cell array of strings
outcome = {'Heads', 'Tails'};

%// Use the vector of 1s and 2s to get our desired strings
y = outcome(x)
```

... and we get:

```
y = 

  Columns 1 through 7

    'Tails'    'Heads'    'Tails'    'Heads'    'Heads'    'Tails'    'Tails'

  Columns 8 through 10

    'Tails'    'Heads'    'Tails'
```

Note that `y` will be a cell array of strings, and so if you want to access a particular string, do:

```
str = y{idx};
```

`idx` is the position of where you want to access.

---

However, if I can suggest something else, you can try using [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) and specify the maximum value of what you want to generate to be 2.  This way, you are guaranteed to produce values between 1 and 2 like so:

```
x = randi(2, 10, 1);
```

This would generate a `10 x 1` array of values that are either 1 or 2.  To me this looks more readable, but whatever you're comfortable with.  You can then use this result and directly access `outcome` to get what you want.

Comment: How I can find the sum of only 1's from x array - that is how many Heads are there-, I mean how can I iterate through array elements?

Comment: I'll answer that when I go to work. I need to go to bed, but as a hint, use `accumarray` or `histc`.

Comment: @AMH9 - All you have to do is: `out = histc(x, [1 2]);`, assuming that you had to offset the array by 1 so that it consists of 1s and 2s.  `out` will be a two-element array that tells you how many times you have seen a 1 (first element) and a 2 (second element).